# Numpy Array - Audio file

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, scipy

I am trying to analyze some audio file. I am using several helper function that helps me to do some data transformations task.

```
from typing import List, Tuple
import webrtcvad
import numpy.typing as npt
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write

vad = webrtcvad.Vad()
vad.set_mode(2)


def _validate_array_dtype(array: npt.NDArray):
  if not isinstance(array, np.ndarray):
    raise ValueError(f"Chunk has to be type np.ndarray but is {type(array)}")
  if array.dtype != np.int16:
    raise ValueError(
      f"Chunk array has to be dtype np.int16 but is {array.dtype}")


def is_speech(frame: npt.NDArray, sample_rate: int) -> bool:
  """Detect if this audio segment is speech or not.

  Args:
    frame: Numpy array (dtype int16) of audio waveform. Duration needs to be exactly 10, 20 or 30 ms.
    sample_rate: Sample rate of the audio frame in Hz.

  Returns:
    Whether this frame contained speech.
  """

  if len(frame.shape) != 1:
    raise ValueError("Frame must be a 1D numpy array.")

  _validate_array_dtype(frame)

  samples_per_ms = (sample_rate) // 1000  # samples for 10 ms
  allowed_lengths = {
    10 * samples_per_ms, 20 * samples_per_ms, 30 * samples_per_ms
  }

  if frame.shape[0] not in allowed_lengths:
    raise ValueError("Frame must have duration of either 10, 20 or 30 ms.")

  raw_frame = frame.tobytes()
  return vad.is_speech(raw_frame, sample_rate)


def read_wav(wav_path: str) -> Tuple[int, npt.NDArray]:
  """Read data from a .wav audio file into a numpy array.

  Args:
    wav_path: Path to the wav file to load.

  Returns:
    A tuple containing, the sample rate of the audio file loaded and raw audio data as numpy array (dtype int16).
  """
  return read(wav_path)
```

I am struggling to understand how `is_speech` function is working.
Once I call

```
is_speech(np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.int16),  sample_rate=10)
```

It returns me the following error: `Value error: Frame must have duration of either 10, 20 or 30 ms.`

I pass to `is_speech` 10 elements it returns this error. I can see from definition of function this value error raise(catch), but fail to get how to use this function properly. Would you like to help me how to use this function? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you call `is_speech`(what arguments) ?

Comment: You need to pass a numpy array of np.int16 type and sample_rate which is positional argument. Use this as example 
is_speech(np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], dtype=np.int16),  sample_rate=10)

Comment: Note that with `sample_rate` at 10 (which is very unrealistic), `sample_per_ms` will be 0 (`samples_per_ms = (sample_rate) // 1000`). `//` is the integer division. `10//1000 = 0`. So `allowed_length` is `{0,0,0}` aka `{0}`. If you want a list of 10 values to be a legal input for `is_speech`, then `sample_rate` as to be 1000 (which is also unrealistic, but at least, if would do something).

Comment: More realisticly, `sample_rate` is `44100` or `48000` (once upon a time 16000 or even 8000 were also quite common values, but not anymore, since the days we aren't happy with low quality sound), so. legal size for `is_speech` with `sample_rate=44100`, would be 440, 880 and 1320.

Comment: (It is a bit strange to use a integer division for `sample_per_ms`, and then mulpitly by 10, 20 30. I would have used a float division  to have `sample_per_ms=44.1`, and then multiply by 10,20,30 and rounded the result, to have `441, 882, 1323` possible values. But, well, I take that `is_speech` is not your code)

Comment: @chrslg
 Would like to show me your refactor code of  `is_speech` function. How should look like as per your point of view?